# mySQL - Count function without Group BY

Tags: mysql

I have difficulty including the WHERE function in my code.

First, I need to Select the idEmploye that is there 2 or more times.

This is my code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT idEmploye, 
       COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY LEFT(idEmploye,2) ORDER BY idEmploye) AS nbrProjet 
FROM RessourcesProjet;
```

This is the results:

```
+-----------+-----------+
| idEmploye | nbrProjet |
|      1212 |         1 |
|      1876 |         2 |
|      2231 |         2 |
|      4354 |         1 |
+-----------+-----------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

This is what I want:

```
+-----------+-----------+
| idEmploye | nbrProjet |
|      1876 |         2 |
|      2231 |         2 | 
+-----------+-----------+
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to SO. See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the result-set from your current query as [Derived Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html); and then do further filtering on it:

```
SELECT dt.* 
FROM 
(
  SELECT DISTINCT idEmploye, 
                  COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY LEFT(idEmploye,2) 
                                ORDER BY idEmploye) AS nbrProjet 
  FROM RessourcesProjet
) AS dt 
WHERE dt.nbrProjet >= 2
```

Comment: @williammorotti I have given a link on the Derived Table in my answer. That should give you complete details. Basically it is a sub-select query (like a temporary table), which we can use further (like nested queries)

Comment: @williammorotti `dt` is just an alias. You can choose any name as alias. Thing is that every Derived table needs to have an alias.

Comment: Thanks for the link!